# Unit Testing Angular Js with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a piece of angular code that does a post request to the cloudant, returns a response, builds a URL with it and does a get request with the same. The get request returns an array buffer through which i build a PDF file to be rendered in the front end.

Could someone please let advice me on how to unit test this as unit testing along with rest API is a new territory for me . PFB my code

```
$scope.viewfile = function(name) {
                $http({
                method : 'POST',
                url : '/search/searchFiles',    
                data : {'currentdropdownvalue' : name} ,
            }).
            success(function(data){ 
                if (!angular.isUndefined(data.docs[0])){
                $scope.file = data.docs[0]._id;
                var fileUrl = $scope.cloudantUrl + $scope.file +"/"+ $scope.file;       
                $http.get(fileUrl {responseType:'arraybuffer'})
                .success(function (response) {
                     var file = new Blob([response], {type: 'application/pdf'});
                     var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                     $scope.content = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(fileURL);
                     $scope.contentType = "application/pdf";
                     $scope.contentWords = null;
                }).error(function(data){
                    console.log("Printing Error inside Post of view " , data);
                }); 
                }
                     else{
                        $scope.content = null;
                        $scope.contentWords = "File is not available for the selected Name";
                     }



            }).
            error(function(data){ 
                console.log("Printing Error inside view  " , data);
            });
        };
    }
```

Comment: You can use $httpBackend to mock out the Http calls

Comment: could you please post a mock up or some sample so that I can use that idea and build it up

Comment: I would have to just refer your to their docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend I am far from an expert on $httpBackend.  I usually just put a spy on the $http object and make it return stuff I feel like it does basically the same thing; your supposed to use $httpBackend though.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should probably use $httpBackend but I usually just end up putting a spy on these functions.  Heres some sudo code using spyOn:

```
    it('Should test viewFile', function() {
        spyOn($http, 'POST').andReturn(mock_data);
        spyOn($http, 'GET').andCallFake(function(fileUrl) {
            expect(fileUrl).toBe($scope.cloudantUrl + $scope.file +"/"+ $scope.file);
        });
        $scope.viewFile(mocked_name).then(function() {
            expect($scope.content).toBe($sce.trustAsResourceUrl(fileURL));
            expect($scope.contentType).toBe("application/pdf");
            expect($scope.contentWords.toBe(null);
        });

        $rootScope.$apply();
    });
```